# WordPress Custom Sort order in Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a WordPress loop to display some data in a table, my code here is as follows:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span>#</span></th>
                <th><span>Model</span></th>
                <th><span>Brand</span></th>
                <th><span>Type</span></th>
                <th><span>Votes</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            $i = 1;
            $args = array(
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'cars',
                'orderby' => 'comment_count',
                'order'   => 'DESC'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
            
            <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php 
                        $totalUpVotes = bpvm_get_vote_counts_meta($post->ID) > 0 ? bpvm_get_vote_counts_meta($post->ID) : 'N/A';
                    ?>
                    <tr class="cartable">
                        <td><span><?php echo $i; $i++;?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php the_field('car_model');?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php the_field('car_brand');?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php the_field('car_type');?></span></td>
                        <td><span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $totalUpVotes?></a></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- End single top-seller -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

While the first 3-4 columns are pretty standard coming from ACF, the last one (Votes) outputs a number from a Plugin called BW Voting Manager. Until here is all good and the values all show up correctly, however what I am trying to achieve is to change the actual sort order which is currently set to **'orderby' => 'comment_count',** to the actual number of votes. So the Post with the highest number of votes should be in first position in my table.

I've tried to change it to something like 'orderby' => $totalUpVotes however I am having no luck with that so I am assuming that's wrong.

Not sure if this helps but I have also checked in the database and there would be a value inside **wp_postmeta** with the meta_key **pvm_like_votes_count**

What's the best way to have this achieved? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Managed to fix it by changing it to:

```
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'pvm_like_votes_count',
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: Okay thank you, that was easy enough. Fixed it and updated my post